# ajax data into different tabs

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I know many will be aware of this example.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
// getuser.php is seprate php file. q is parameter 
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form>
    <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
      <option value="">Select a person:</option>
      <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
      <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
      <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
      <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

But imagine I have different tabs on the page. Inside which there are different variants of the div txtHint such txtHome, txtMenu1, txtMenu2 etc.. and clicking on those divs should retrieve various php pages through the javascript such as `"gethome.php?q="+str` and `"getmenu1.php?q="+str` and likewise.. then how to do it ?? please help

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu1</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu2</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu3</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Menu4</a></li>
</ul>
           
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
<h3>HOME</h3>
<div id="txtHome">
</div>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
              <h3>Menu1</h3>
<div id="txtMenu1">
</div>
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">     <h3>Menu2</h3>
<div id="txtMenu2">
</div>
</div>
<div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">     <h3>Menu3</h3>
<div id="txtMenu3">
</div>
</div>
<div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade">     <h3>Menu4</h3>
<div id="txtMenu4">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" onClick="getDataFor('txtMenu1','your_custom_data')">Menu1</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" onClick="getDataFor('txtMenu2','your_custom_data')">Menu2</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3" onClick="getDataFor('txtMenu3','your_custom_data')">Menu3</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4" onClick="getDataFor('txtMenu4','your_custom_data')">Menu4</a></li>
div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <h3>HOME</h3>
  <div id="txtHome"> </div>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Menu1</h3>
  <div id="txtMenu1"> </div>
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Menu2</h3>
  <div id="txtMenu2"> </div>
</div>
<div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Menu3</h3>
  <div id="txtMenu3"> </div>
</div>
<div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Menu4</h3>
  <div id="txtMenu4"> </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    function getDataFor(tabId,dataId) {

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById(tabId).innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  var url = "example.php?data="+dataId;
  xhttp.open("GET",url, true);
  xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```